# Redux updating item in state array

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update the building's name and image when the user clicks edit . I am dispatching the action correctly I think my logic with trying to copy the previous `state` and updating it with the new value is wrong because I am not seeing the value getting updated. It is just returning the previous state .Please can some help me out!

This is my code:

```
import MyBuilding from '../../models/MyBuilding'
import { CREATE_BUILDING, DELETE_BUILDING , UPDATE_BUILDING} from '../actions/building'

const initialState = {
    building: [],
}
const BuildingReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case CREATE_BUILDING:
            const newBuilding = new MyBuilding(
                action.buildingData.id,
                action.buildingData.name,
                action.buildingData.image, 
            )
            return { ...state, building: state.building.concat(newBuilding)}

        case DELETE_BUILDING:
            const filteredItems = state.building.filter(cb => cb.id !== action.deleteCB)
            return {...state, building: filteredItems }

        case UPDATE_BUILDING:
            const updatedItems = state.building.map(cb => cb.id === action.updateItem.id ? 
                {...cb, 
                    name: action.updateItem.name,
                    image: action.updateItem.image} : cb
                )
            return {...state, 
                building: updatedItems }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
export default BuildingReducer
```

Comment: What do the redux devtools say? What action was dispatched with what data and how did it change the state? Are you sure that building id and action updateItem id are o the same type? When they are not then nothing will be changed because 1 !== "1"

Answer (score 0):

Components connected with the store basically talks with the Redux state only.
example

```
let state = {
building: [1,2,3]
}

console.log({ ...state, building: state.building.concat([4,5,6])}) // you will see all building here 
console.log(state) // but the actual state has not changed
```

Assign the state to the changes you want and then return that state

```
case CREATE_BUILDING:
const newBuilding = new MyBuilding(
    action.buildingData.id,
    action.buildingData.name,
    action.buildingData.image,
)
state = { ...state, building: state.building.concat(newBuilding) } // do this
return state
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So basically I have to update the buildings state with the new object .By calling the new Building model. So is the way I am doing the UPDATE_BUILDING correct because that is what my question was referring to

Comment: your approach looks good to me. Just keep in mind whenever you are using spread operators it creates a copy of your object and doses not impact the original object. So in case you want to change the original object you have to assign the object with the updated value.

Comment: Please could you show me the right way to update it then in the `UPDATE_COOKBOOK` action. I don't really know how to do it